# XCode complaining about viewDidLoad and "Missing @end" (iAd)

Tags: ios, objective-c

So as you can see here, XCode is complaining, but I don't know why, so... what's wrong with my code? And I've imported the iAd framework. XCode is complaining about -(void)viewDidLoad and it says : "missing @end"

So what's wrong with my code?

The .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    ADBannerView *banner;
    UILabel *label;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL bannerIsVisible;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;

@end
```

The .m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize banner, bannerIsVisible;


-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)abannar {
    if(!self.bannerIsVisible) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, 50.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;


    }
}


-(void)bannerView: (ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {


    if(!self.bannerIsVisible) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bottom of your .m file has been chopped off. You need a closing `}` for the bannerView method and the `@end` at the end of the file to close the `@implementation` section.

It looks like you are also be missing the `#import` at the top of the .m file, where you import the .h file.

Comment: Oke thanks, I had imported the viewcontroller.h file already, but i didn't copied it. But, thanks for your help!